# How do you sort an array (list) of strings in chronological order, different from the built-in sort function?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

**EDIT NOTE: See below, I require files to be sorted on modified date instead.**

I have been breaking my mind on this one for quite some time:

I have an array of strings of pathnames, log files. I want to delete the oldest ones when a certain amount/size for the log files is reached.

The format for the filenames is: the date, the how manieth log of that date + .log

e.g. `"2016-10-19-#1.log", "2016-10-19-#2.log", "2016-10-19-#3.log"`

when I sort using `Collections.sort(arrayList);` the entries `"2016-10-19-#1.log", "2016-10-19-#2.log" and "2016-10-19-#10.log"` will be sorted into #1, #10 and #2. instead of #1, #2 and #10

What I am aiming for is to ultimately have the oldest log files be deleted.

Here a code snippet:

```
File directory = new File(pathToDir);
FilenameFilter fnf = new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".log");
    }
};

int dirCount = directory.listFiles(fnf).length;
if (dirCount > maxLogCache) {
    for(File file2 : directory.listFiles(fnf)) {
        file2.delete();
        dirCount--;
            if (dirCount <= maxLogCache) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will delete files in order #1, #10, #11, #2, #3 ... if files #1 through #11 exist.

**NEW EDIT**
*sorry for the style*

Instead of using the string of the filename to sort the array(list), it is required to get the lastModified date from the File.

```
File directory = new File(pathToDir);
FilenameFilter fnf = new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".log");
    }
};    
int dirCount = directory.listFiles(fnf).length;
// Code for sorting based on lastModified.
```

Comment: The only work around I could think of is using #0001 and #0010, aka leading zeroes... which is ok I guess, but I rather have it without.

Comment: You could sort based on file name, then convert your manieth number to an int and sort each date section based on that.

Comment: As an alternative, you can sort files [by date, literally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified())

Comment: I now just figured, deleting #0 and re-running the application, will generate file #0 again because it doesn't exist anymore. The way I implemented it. so I think I should change this to sorting on date modified.

Comment: thanks anyway somebody can close this post as duplicate, well after I edited it because my requirements changed :/ blargh, hate it when your brain pulls you through a mangle bath like this.